# Разное поведение скрипта в SQL Editor и в обычной функции

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть метод в пакете в Oracle. В нем мне нужно получить запись, у которой поле GUIDID (Уникальный идентификатор) равно заданному мной (запрос ниже). Но в функции это работает не так, как в SQL Editor - запрос возвращает 7 строк вместо 1, если бы запрос был выполнен в SQL Editor.

```
SELECT Z.ID, Z.MUNICID
INTO pID, peopleMunicID
FROM (
  SELECT ID, MUNICID
  FROM PEOPLE
  WHERE GUIDID IS NOT NULL AND
        GUIDID = guidID
  ORDER BY ID DESC
) Z 
WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```

Сама функция:

```
  function getChildCardID(
    chID in integer,
    mID in varchar2
  ) return integer
  is
    guidID varchar2(100 CHAR);
    pID NUMBER;
    rN NUMBER;
    childID integer;
    peopleMunicID varchar2(100 CHAR);
  begin
    SELECT DISTINCT PEOPLE.GUIDID
    INTO guidID
    FROM CHILD
    INNER JOIN PEOPLE
      ON CHILD.PEOPLEID = PEOPLE.ID AND
         CHILD.MUNICID = PEOPLE.MUNICID
    WHERE CHILD.ID = chID AND
          CHILD.MUNICID = mID;

    IF (guidID IS NULL or guidID = '') THEN
      return chID;
    END IF;

    SELECT Z.ID, Z.MUNICID
    INTO pID, peopleMunicID
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT ID, MUNICID
      FROM PEOPLE
      WHERE GUIDID = guidID
      ORDER BY ID
    ) Z 
    WHERE ROWNUM < 2;

    IF (pID IS NULL or pID = '') THEN
      return chID;
    END IF;

    SELECT DISTINCT CHILD.ID
    INTO childID
    FROM CHILD
    WHERE CHILD.PEOPLEID = pID and
          CHILD.MUNICID = peopleMunicID and
          ROWNUM < 2;

    IF (childID IS NULL) THEN
      return chID;
    END IF; 

    return childID;   
  end getChildCardID;
```

Comment: порядок строк не гарантирован до тех пор, пока не определен порядок сортировки. Скорее всего внутри процедуры Oracle выбирает другой план выполнения и из за этого меняется порядок строк, т.е. строкой с ROWNUM=1 становится другая строка. Следует сначала отсиртировать выборку, потом заключить ее в еще один select и уже у него использовать условие по ROWNUM

Comment: @Mike, сделал так, сейчас добавлю код в вопрос. Не помогло, только после сортировка DESC, вывел ID 68, а не 1.

Comment: distinct из верхнего запроса уберите. для поиска уникальных значений Oracle вынужден применять сортировку (потому что сортировка один из самых быстрых способов нахождения уникальных значений)

Comment: @Mike, все еще так же, DISTINCT убрал

Comment: сортировка ASC означает, что первой строкой будет запись с ID=1 (если она есть). Если вам нужна не ID=1 то сделайте сортироку такой, что бы все таки первой строкой была именно требуемая. (без rownum выполняйте запрос и смотрите какая запись первая). Вы еще что то говорили про значение второго поля. Если оно отличается для одного peopleid то вероятно его то же надо указывать в сортировке, что бы определить какое из них нужно

Comment: @Mike, у меня в данном запросе для того количества данных, в sql editor возвращает всего одну запись

Comment: Эммм ... без условия ROWNUM<2 только одну запись ? а зачем тогда нужно это условие ?

Comment: Опишите исходную задачу. Найти минимальный `CHILD.PEOPLEID` и соответствующий ему `PEOPLE.MUNICID`? Что-то подобное проще сделать через аналитические функции.

Comment: @Mike, это тестовые данные, хоть и не в полной мере (по количеству записей). В последствии их может больше одной записи при такой выборке.

Comment: @Dmitry, задача в том, чтобы при заданном запросе, получить из функции те же данные, что и из sql editor.

Comment: SQL editor может использовать "hints"... Чтобы понять что происходит сравните планы выполнения в обоих случаях. PS а вообще `SELECT` без `ORDER BY` не гарантирует порядок возвращаемых записей (как вам уже объяснил @Mike)

Comment: @VladislavKuznetsov см. [проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)

Comment: @Dmitry, поправил задачу

Comment: @VladislavKuznetsov Может вы лучше функцию покажете? Будет понятнее о чём речь.

Comment: @0xdb, добавил!

Comment: @VladislavKuznetsov Да, но спорной  выборки я там не вижу , и кроме того, последния выбоорка никогда не будет выполнена.

Comment: @0xdb, не тот вариант функции скинул, там запрос тестовый, а не тот, который нужен был вставлен, в конце дня скидывал, не углядел (Исправил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смог сам решить вопрос - в условии у меня стоит GUIDID = guidID. Это условие было проблемным, что в общем то логично так то. Я поменял имя переменной на отличное от названия поля и теперь все заработало корректно.

```
SELECT Z.ID, Z.MUNICID
INTO pID, peopleMunicID
FROM (
  SELECT ID, MUNICID
  FROM PEOPLE
  WHERE GUIDID IS NOT NULL AND
    GUIDID = peopleGuidID <= Здесь
  ORDER BY ID DESC
) Z 
WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```